# Review edit warning lingers on

Tags: bug, edits, user-interface

The warning about an edit being made to a post you are yourself currently editing hangs around long after it should have gone away.

> [image]

In this instance I had opened the `edited` link supplied by the warning in a new tab to review the edit that got in before me. After looking through it, I submitted my own without dismissing the dialogue.

---

I would expect the warning to disappear after it becomes useless. Either:

- Submitting/cancelling your pending edit,
- Navigating away from the edit page.

I'm using FireFox 31.0 on Linux, but don't have any remaining reviews left to attempt to duplicate it in other browsers or OS's at the moment but can do tomorrow, if need be.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: No question, a bug report. I'll clarify above