# Can we allow users with 500 <= reputation < 10k to view deleted posts that they personally reviewed?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

### Reasoning

I feel it's a missed opportunity for learning and improving the reviewer base.

If I want to scroll back through my browser history/list of recent reviews -- to see how other people interpreted the posts to either confirm I made a good judgement call or better understand where I may have gone wrong -- it would be very beneficial to be able to view the post in question if it were deleted.

Right now there's no way to evaluate what you did wrong or didn't catch if you voted against the majority on a post that gets removed unless you have +10k rep to see the post (as you would normally be able to for any deleted post) or by having an eidetic memory.

---

### Caching services

@Sam pointed out that, at least for posts that were able to survive long enough to get scraped and cached, it is possible to use one of any number of web caching services.
While this is true I believe I'm right in assuming that the vast majority of posts that get the deletion treatment are caught early and never get the opportunity to live on in infamy.

As such, while it's a hit or miss workaround for the way things currently are it is certainly not a great solution to be suggested to people to use in the future.

---

### Current functionality:

Currently this is how things appear for those below 10k for those above it.
(*Thanks to @Sam for the examples*)

#### Deleted Questions show as:

> [image: deleted question]

#### Deleted Answers show as:

> [image: deleted answer]

---

### Rep limits

Following @DanNeely's point below about reducing my initial lower limit of 2k to 500 as these users have access to review queues where this may also occur has got me asking why not open the viewing of all reviews to any registered user?

Insight to and an improved transparency of how the community makes its decisions in relation to unwelcome material can only benefit any user that may want to see the process in action and thus lead them into making better decisions themselves about how they formulate their own posts and submitting flags that are more in line with how the community is actually acting upon flags.

If it were a question of hiding people's names from possible revenge type voting or harassment from low-rep users who have not proved they can act appropriately on the site then of course, keep a lower rep limit or mask them for user who wouldn't ordinarily be able to see them.

---

### TL;DR

So I guess after some back and forth in the comments and a few edits the proposal has a few main points or choices.

**Implement any of:**

- Allow any user to see a deleted post that they performed a review action on (**including skip!**).
- Allow any user **of sufficient rep** to view a deleted post when viewed through a review link (*not by normal in-line Question/Answer links*).
- Allow **ANY** user (*optionally registered/logged in*) to view a deleted post when following a review link.

---

### Similar / duplicate

Brad has pointed out that he has [a similar request for this on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed) with further reasoning from a moderator's perspective.

> So moderators just got the ability to provide custom reasons when they ban users from review. Often, these bans are due to specific very bad reviews, like approving spam or non-answers. It will be common for us to give links to these bad reviews in the ban message that the reviewers will be presented with.
>
> ...
>
> I propose that reviewers of any reputation level be able to see posts that they reviewed, even ones that were later deleted, if they are presented with a link to their review. They already saw the post once, so there's no harm in showing it to them again, and reviewers are going to need to see why they made a bad call on a particular review.

Comment: Or, if the post wasn't recently created, you could [view a cached version](http://www.cachedpages.com/). A good idea nethertheless +1.

Comment: I agree.  But just to be clear, are you sure you can't see the review itself still (which would show you the part of the post you reviewed)?  Or are you specifically asking to see the rest of the question/answers that weren't part of the review.

Comment: @Sam Guess that's a possibility but a bit of a round-a-bout solution. Also, although I'm not going over to data.so to confirm it, I feel that the vast majority of posts are caught and flagged very early on making it not a viable option.

Comment: @Joe The post itself. We can see the ways the votes were cast and access the stats of our fellow reviewers but it either shows "Answer not found" and the question text for a deleted answer or [actually can't recall the placeholder for a deleted question off the top of my head right now].

Comment: @indivisible Of course; I did only suggest that as a partial workaround while the feature is being developed. It's still better than nothing though.

Comment: @Joe I just flicked back through my history for today's activity and only don't have any examples to check. If a post is closed/put on hold is is viewable but I think that deleted may 404. I'll come back and update once I have an example and can confirm/refute that.

Comment: @Sam I got what you meant but felt that pointing out the flaws might help promote the feature request as even a good workaround falls very short of helping all that much. Not an attack on your suggestion, just a snag list.

Comment: @indivisible Sure, I understand. D'you think it might be a good idea to state that in your proposal then?

Comment: Hmm, I don't have any accounts in the 2k-10k (or beta equivalent) range, unfortunately, so I can't check; but I thought reviews were always visible (the review itself, not the post).

Comment: @Joe [Exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5246096).

Comment: Actually, [meta.se] is one such site for me, but I haven't reviewed any since deleted posts.  But to be clear, what I'm referring to is clicking on the "Close" (or whatever action you took), rather than the post title.

Comment: @Sam yep, that's what I was thinking.  For you, that works (you can see what it was you reviewed - the post starting with "I'm confused" - or does it show up as not visible?)

Comment: @Joe I can only see the question, not the answer I reviewed (I only get "*answer not found*").

Comment: @Sam Hmm, okay.  That does seem like you ought to be able to see (the review).  I wonder if this is an oversight caused by the relatively recent addition of Low Quality posts to the 2k queue - it used to be that you never had reviews that ended up with immediate deletion in the 2k queue.

Comment: @indivisible Deleted posts simply say "*question not found*". ([Exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5246055).)

Comment: @Sam, ty. I'll update my request with the extra info

Comment: IF the change is made, it should be available to 500-2000 rep users as well.  They have access to the first post/late answer queue's and are more likely to need to fine tune their dis/approve threshold.

Comment: @DanNeely, very good point. I'll modify the title and proposal. I've a few follow on thoughts from this that I'll add above too.

Comment: Deleted reviews that were shown as review *audits* are still shown and do not result in the "not found" messages.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi That's because SE wanted to make them even more annoyingly special.

Comment: @Sam I'd much prefer a notification bar similar to the "this post has been edited" one but that's a post for another day.

Comment: ["Allow all reviewers to see deleted posts they reviewed"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed)

Comment: @indivisible A notification bar for what?

Comment: @Sam For successfully passing an audit. I've seen someone say that they intentionally skip audits just to avoid the second "huzzah and congratulations" page that follows.

Comment: @indivisible Oh right. Hmm, I think that might be a little too much IMHO. Getting an inbox notification just to say you've passed an audit doesn't seem the best way to remove the annoyance from clicking one more time for an audit. Personally, I don't find it that irritating, but that's just me...

Comment: @BradLarson, thanks, I've added a link to that.

Comment: @Sam Not an inbox notification. I mean the orange bar that pops up floated at the top of your page while you are editing a post and another edit squeezes in between when you start and before you submit your changes.

Comment: @indivisible Now that sounds like a decent improvement.

Comment: @Sam Go ahead and propose it if you wish. One a day is enough for me. But please include mention of the bug that doesn't clear the notification when you navigate away from the page. I submitted a post about it a while back but it didn't get any traction: [review-edit-warning-lingers-on](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260874/review-edit-warning-lingers-on). While not entirely related to a proposal of that sort the implementation of it would likely duplicate the bug.

Comment: @indivisible Thanks, but it's *your* idea, so I'll let you propose it. You'll probably be better at explaining it anyway (I didn't even know the bug existed).

Answer (score 45):

I would suggest that this be implemented by allowing the review to be viewed, specifically (not the post in the general setting).  IE, it should look something like this, even to a 2k user, when browsing in his/her past review history (clicking on the "Recommend Deletion" link):
[image]

This wouldn't enable the original post to be visible directly.

Comment: Oh definitely. It would be wasted effort trying to bend the normal viewing procedure alongside the review review view (*that has a nice ring to it*) to take a user's previous review history into account for the entirety of all posts being displayed and wasted resources performing those checks.

Comment: I disagree. I think it should still be like that, but it would be much simpler to just add "X reviewed this post" to the list of "it's deleted can you still view it" checks... It would literally be harder to not "bend the normal viewing procedure" than it would to leave it as it is.

Comment: @corsiKa, not knowing for sure the way things are structured, abstracted and combined I can't speak to the actual difficulty but I assumed modifying the functionality of an already different view would be less controversial, easier to get accepted and less work to implement than a site-wide change. [open review --> if requester in reviewers --> display regardless] check in one relatively infrequently requested page than an extra verification on almost every single page load for the site. As I said, I may be wrong but wouldn't every request count when talking about a site/network of this scale?

Comment: I don't think that will ever be implemented for *all* reviews, as that's too much of a loophole, more a wide-open door. For all reviews you yourself made though...