# Should every recommendation of a tool by its owner be considered spam?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, spam

I recently reviewed a VLQ answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5890571) (the answer is already deleted but I guess 10k users would still see it), and after much consideration voted to leave it. I was almost sure that most users would see it as spam, and it could be considered promotional, but it was in fact a recommendation for a tool that did exactly what was asked for in the question. The author affiliation was not hidden, he actually named his user after the tools name, and he published only a single answer.

I thought that the right course of action was to leave the answer, as it suits the question and is informative and not excessively promotional, and just vote to close the question as a request for an off site resource. I think the discussion here reached a similar conclusion - [When is spam not spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265628/when-is-spam-not-spam)

Since the community did not agree with me, i'm now blocked for a week from VLQ review. Ironically, i'm one of those who asked for such a penalty to be instated (so I don't mind "paying" the penalty), but i'm really wondering if this spam should truly be considered spam.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For reference, this was the post:

[image]

That's pretty clearly spam. It's a feature list for a commercial product, posted by a 1-rep user (whose only other post promoted this product). It does not address the specific question asked. They were also a pretty lazy spammer, as they quickly pasted their link at the end without even adding a description.

Posts like this should be flagged, and clicking "No Action Needed" in review is harmful, as all it takes is one person approving this to let spam like this live on the site. In fact, I had to deal with a massive spam ring this morning that posted dozens of spam answers across six accounts all because a few reviewers approved their first posts and let them continue.

We need reviewers to be very suspicious of first-time posters whose answers promote commercial products. Even if you don't feel a spam flag is warranted, cast a custom moderator flag, and let us know about potentially suspicious behavior. We can use our tools to see if this is part of a larger problem.

Comment: Didn't know a single accept can block a deletion, I thought it was a majority vote. Regardless, pasting the answer alone here does make it look like an advertisement, but keep in mind that the question was more or less "please recommend an OData explorer", which the answer did, even if in an annoying superfluous way. Still, I accept your explanation, will take better care in the future.

Comment: @Leeor The question is irrelevant. http://i.stack.imgur.com/d3X80.png

Answer (score 8):

This question comes up a *lot*. Mostly in emails from plaintive spammers. Here's an analogy I used in a reply I wrote to one yesterday:

> Suppose someone asks a question: "How do I replace the spring in my garage door". Someone else responds with an answer that details the surprisingly tricky and dangerous process for doing this. Then a third person response with,
>
> > You can use MultiSpring, a spring I created to solve problems just like the one you're having! There are other solutions, but they all seem tricky and dangerous.
>
> Now, does that third answer *really* answer the question?
>
> Well, we don't really know - maybe MultiSpring is the best solution out there, turning a job normally best left to professionals into one that anyone can do, with almost zero chance of being ripped apart by a tightly-coiled spring. Maybe it works for every design of door, ever, even those crazy old ones with the big lever arms off to the side. Maybe it even comes with all the necessary hardware for both removing the old spring and attaching the new one, and instructions so simple they hardly warrant publishing at all... Or maybe it's all crap, just some huckster trying to hawk bulk springs on every website he can find. Point is, **we don't know *because the answer doesn't bother trying to answer any of the questions that would let us know*.** There's nothing to verify, nothing to compare or contrast, no instructions to follow or specific advantages to consider.
>
> An acceptable answer to that question would **describe how to accomplish the task at hand**, with any necessary tools or supplies being little more than a side-note.

Comment: It's a nice analogy, but the discussion is not whether it's a *good* answer (obviously not, even if there was no spam concern), but whether it's an answer at all

Comment: You *were* in the "Low Quality" queue... Abysmally bad answers are fair game.

Answer (score 5):

Recommendation questions aren't welcome on the site to begin with, so what you should be doing is going to the question and closing/deleting it.  So long as the question is handled the answers aren't so important, however in cases such as this where the account is a spam account, it is important to be able to get the attention of a moderator to be able to cleanse the entire account with fire (in the event that it's necessary) so for that reason it's best to mark the spam answers of spam accounts accordingly.

Comment: I didn't think that a single answer merits labeling this as a spam account, but you do have a point that a user called after his own tool is probably up to no good..

Comment: @Leeor A moderator has already deleted the entire account, so we can't see what other actions the user may have taken, but presumably the mod felt that there was sufficient evidence to delete the account.

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time a spammer created one account to ask the question, and another to answer it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth They usually don't wait *four years* to answer the question when that's the case.  Spammers also love to search for very old unclosed recommendation questions that simply slipped through the net and didn't get closed, which appears to have been the case here.

Comment: Agreed, it could have been a case of someone looking for the right question to promote his product.